# Md-Tabs or Md-Nav-Tabs within Md-menu Event Keeps Propagating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, dom-events

I'm trying to have md-tabs or md-nav-tabs within a md-menu. Yes I know it is not good practice, but it does what I need, perfectly, if only it would stay open as the tabs are clicked.

So I found some answers here. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4334 but the `$timeout` isn't working right. Is there a solution to get this working? Is there an alternative. I really like animation of the sliding line under the horizontal buttons, and it is bonus points with the other animations.

So here is the code:

```
  $scope.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, $event) {
  var menu = $mdOpenMenu($event);
  $timeout(function() {
    var menuContent = document.getElementById('durationcontent');

    function hasAnyAttribute(target, attrs) {
      if (!target) return false;
      for (var i = 0, attr; attr = attrs[i]; ++i) {
        var altForms = [attr, "data-" + attr, "x-" + attr];
        for (var j = 0, rawAttr; rawAttr = altForms[j]; ++j) {
          if (target.hasAttribute(rawAttr)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    };

    function getClosest(el, tagName, onlyParent) {
      if (el instanceof angular.element) el = el[0];
      tagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
      if (onlyParent) el = el.parentNode;
      if (!el) return null;
      do {
        if (el.nodeName === tagName) {
          return el;
        }
      } while (el = el.parentNode);
      return null;
    };
    menuContent.parentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log('clicked');
      var target = e.target;
      do {
        if (target === menuContent) return;
        if (hasAnyAttribute(target, ["ng-click", "ng-href", "ui-sref", "md-nav-click"]) || target.nodeName == "MD-TAB" || target.nodeName == "BUTTON" || target.nodeName == "LI") {
          var closestMenu = getClosest(target, "MD-MENU");
          if (!target.hasAttribute("disabled") && (!closestMenu || closestMenu == opts.parent[0])) {
            if (target.hasAttribute("md-menu-disable-close")) {
              event.stopPropagation();
              angular.element(target).triggerHandler('click');
            }
            return; //let it propagate
          }
          break;
        }
      } while (target = target.parentNode);
    }, true);
  });
};

}]);
```

I made a few tweaks to look for the right directives. It's original author, @clshortfuse github says it "You need to intercept the click event on md-menu-content. From there you can handle if the event propagates. You can call stopPropagation immediately and handle click events on your own."

```
          <md-menu ng-repeat="shoe in shoes">
        <button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
          {{shoe.type}}
        </button>
        <md-menu-content>
          <div ng-include="shoe.template"></div>
          <p>the size is {{shoe.size}}</p>
        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
```

and within the template

```
      <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" md-selcted="1">
  <!-- ; $event.stopPropagation(); -->
    <md-tab ng-repeat="w in shoe.wearers" label="{{$index +1}}"  md-menu-disable-close="md-menu-disable-close"  ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
      <md-content>{{w}}</md-content>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
```

I want the ux, of the horizontal sliding bar menu more than anything. I'm open to other suggestions, anything will help.

And, of course, here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JhDhwkhO9RwLcuzDKU0v?p=preview